# Theano input and output sample number error

Tags: python, neural-network, theano, keras

I am working on some project and I need to use neural network in python. I am trying to train neural network but I always get error for FIT() function. This is my code:

```
def matrix_to_vector(m):
    return m.flatten()


def prepare_for_rnn(tones):
    ready_for_rnn = []
    for tone in tones:
        ready_for_rnn.append(matrix_to_vector(tone))

    return ready_for_rnn

def convert_output2(outputs):
    return np.eye(len(outputs))

tone = LoadDataSet('samples/ddur.wav')

X_train = []
X_train.append(tone.DataSet)


x_train = prepare_for_rnn(X_train)
tones = ['D']
y_train = convert_output2(tones)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(128, input_dim=1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer=sgd)

y_train = np.array(y_train)

print x_train
print y_train
print y_train.shape
print len(y_train)

model.fit(x_train, y_train, nb_epoch=2000, batch_size=1, verbose=0, shuffle=False, show_accuracy=False)
score = model.evaluate(x_train, y_train, batch_size=16)
```

I am getting error that my input array and output array haven't same samples number.

my console output:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/misel/PycharmProjects/SoftProjekat/main.py
Using Theano backend.
[array([ 0.70347332,  0.72311571,  2.64259667, ...,  0.52694423,
        0.21127148,  0.43055696])]
[[ 1.]]
(1, 1)
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/misel/PycharmProjects/SoftProjekat/main.py", line 103, in <module>
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, nb_epoch=2000, batch_size=1, verbose=0, shuffle=False, show_accuracy=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 503, in fit
    raise Exception('All input arrays and the target array must '
Exception: All input arrays and the target array must have the same number of samples.
```

Comment: `model.add(Dense(1, input_dim=128, activation='sigmoid'))`

Comment: also this is redundant `model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))`

Comment: might want to y_train to be `[1]` instead of `[[1]]`

Answer (score 1):

I was implementing Autoencoders when I got this problem saying "Exception: All input arrays and the target array must have the same number of samples.".
model.fit expects numpy array as input.

```
X: data, as a numpy array.
y: labels, as a numpy array.
```

converting list to numpy array solved my problem.

If we see the documentation of model.fit it says:

```
if type(X) == list:
            if len(set([len(a) for a in X] + [len(y)])) != 1:
                raise Exception('All input arrays and the target array must ''have the same number of samples.')
```

so if X is of type list: length of all the items in the list X and length of list y should be same else the exception will be raised.